# java Need regex to extract weeknumbers from string

Tags: java, regex

I got a list of magazine names which may contain one or more weeknumbers.
Example:

> Soccer International wk43
>  National Geopgraphic (wk50)
>   Schoolpaper wk39/wk43
>  Some magazine week12 until 16
>  Another
>   magazine wk36_38
>  Another magazine wk36_wk38

Etc.
What I want is to get the last part as week.
So:

> Soccer International week 43
>  National Geopgraphic week 50
>   Schoolpaper week 39 - week 43
>  Some magazine week12 - week 16
>   Another magazine week 36 - week38
>  Another magazine week 36 - week
>   38

I started with:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(wk|week)[\\(\\_]?([0-9]{1,2}\\-?[0-9]{0,2})");
```

But that did not work for:

```
(some wk36 tm 42)", "(some wk36/wk37)", "(some wk36_wk37)", "some wk36_37", "some wk36_wk37"
```

I tried to do the following:
Read up to first occurence of week or wk (wk|week) and get everything after that.

Replace every occurence of wk with week

Somehow replace all non-numeric characters (like /_-).

But I got stuck.
Anyone any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just look for numerical values? Seems like there are only 1-2 numbers per line and those are the weeks.

Comment: Only I the examples I mentioned. If I only get the part after the fiorst occurence of week (or wk) then yes. 
I also tried:
replaceAll("[a-zA-Z\\s]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")

But (eg) wk36_wk38 will then be:
3638.

Comment: Then can you show an example of a line with more then 2 week numbers? Seems like you would want to catch that as well in the regex and should be part of your examples?

Comment: Yes it should be. Sorry I didn think of that. 
A example line:
Advertiser Donald_advXL_NB_EOL_19 dec 15_wk48 tm wk 52

In this case I want: week 48 - week 52
Or: week 48 - 52

Comment: Try [`w(?:e{2})?k(\d+)(?:(?:\s*until\s*|[ _\/])(?:w(?:e{2})?k)?(\d+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/rB3iL3/3). See [code demo](http://ideone.com/jTAZEz).

Comment: Almost exactly what I was looking for! Just need to figure out how to get rid of the second week if there is no second week.
So instead of: 
Soccer International week 43 - week
Soccer International week 43
But I think I can manage :-). Thank you!

Comment: Next time please add the user tag `@<USERNAME>` so that the message reaches the recepient :) I posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Matcher#appendReplacement` with the following regex:

```
(?i)w(?:e{2})?k(\\d+)(?:(?:\\s*until\\s*|[ _\\/])(?:w(?:e{2})?k)?(\\d+))?
```

Here is the [code demo](http://ideone.com/cbuCIo):

```
String rx = "(?i)w(?:e{2})?k(\\d+)(?:(?:\\s*until\\s*|[ _\\/])(?:w(?:e{2})?k)?(\\d+))?"; 
String s = "Soccer International wk43\nNational Geopgraphic (wk50)\nSchoolpaper wk39/wk43\nSome magazine week12 until 16\nAnother magazine wk36_38\nAnother magazine wk36_wk38"; 
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(rx).matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String replacement = m.group(2) == null ? // Check if Group 2 is matched
            "week " + m.group(1):             // If not, use just Group 1
            "week " + m.group(1) + " - week " + m.group(2); // If yes, Group 2 is added
    m.appendReplacement(result, replacement); //  Add the replacement
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

An update for more complex scenario:

```
String rx = "(?i)w(?:e{2})?k\\s*(\\d+)(?: +(\\d{4})\\b)?(?:(?:\\s*(?:until|tm)\\s*|[ _/])(?:w(?:e{2})?k)?(\\d+)(?: +(\\d{4})\\b)?)?"; 
String s = "wk 1 2016\n(wk 47 2015 tm 9 2016)\nSoccer International wk43\nNational Geopgraphic (wk50)\nSchoolpaper wk39/wk43\nSome magazine week12 until 16\nAnother magazine wk36_38\nAnother magazine wk36_wk38"; 
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(); // week 47 (2015) - week 9 (2016)  
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(rx).matcher(s); // week 1 (2016)
while (m.find()) {
    String replacement = "";
    String prt1 = ""; String prt2 = "";
    if (m.group(2) != null) {
        prt1 += " (" + m.group(2) + ")";
    }
    if (m.group(4) != null) {
        prt2 += " (" + m.group(4) + ")";
    }

    if (m.group(3) == null) {
        replacement = "week " + m.group(1) + prt1;
    } else {
        replacement = "week " + m.group(1) + prt1 + " - week " + m.group(3) + prt2;
    }
    m.appendReplacement(result, replacement);
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

The [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/mM6bL2/2)

Comment: Whaah! Thnx! That's it. And more what I expected; using a  Matcher. This is my answer!

Comment: Glad to help. Note that you may get rid of a separate `replacement` variable by using `if` and writing the replacement directly, I just used it for illustration.

Comment: `(?:e{2})` seems a bit cryptic, surely `(?:ee)` would be more straightforward.

Comment: One last thing.
Some magazine wk36 tm 42 does not work.
I would like to accept this answer, but need to look how to do that.

Comment: The separator is `(?:\\s*until\\s*|[ _\\/])`. You can make it "universal" with `\w`: `(?:\\s*\\w+\\s*|[ _\\/])`. Or add more alternatives: `(?:\\s*(?:until+|tm)\\s*|[ _\\/])`

Comment: Unfortunately 2 other cases arose.
(wk 47 2015 tm 9 2016)
I want this as: week 47 (2015) - week 9 (2016).
wk 1 2016
I want that as : week 1 (2016)

Could I trouble you once more?

Comment: See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/mM6bL2/1): `"(?i)w(?:e{2})?k\\s*(\\d+)(?: +(\\d{4})\\b)?(?:(?:\\s*(?:until|tm)\\s*|[ _/])(?:w(?:e{2})?k)?(\\d+)(?: +(\\d{4})\\b)?)?"`. Just add checks for Group 3 and 4 in the code. If you fail, let me know.

Comment: Thnx Wiktor. Got it. Last question for now. Is it possible to strip everything in front of the match?
Say the string = "some other (useless ) text (wk 47 2015 tm 9 2016)";
I only want: (week 47 (2015) - week 9 (2016))

Comment: It depends on what you consider to be useless. Match it and remove with `replaceFirst`. Like `s.replaceFirst("(?s)^.*(\\(week)", "$1")`.